# TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'", 'occurred at index growth(%)')

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, styling, pandas-styles

This is my dataframe --

```
    c2_name Q1_GMV      Q2_GMV     growth(%)
0   A       1170727260  221801763   -81
1   B       1604716749  829186592   -48
2   C       661473481   553698141   -16
```

I've trying to add CSS to the dataframe output using the pandas styling.

```
# Set colormap equal to seaborns light green color palette
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

(df.style
  .background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=['growth(%)'])
  .set_caption('This is a custom caption.')
  .set_table_styles(styles))
```

But getting this error

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'", 'occurred at index growth(%)')
```

Trying to make it look something like this

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqNzv.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are using `Decimal` instead of float? That seems to be the root of your problem. In your above example, it's totally unnecessary given the values in that column. You can solve your problem with:

```
df['growth(%)'] = df['growth(%)'].astype('float')
```

---

Example:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

print(df)
#  c2_name      Q1_GMV     Q2_GMV  growth(%)
#0       A  1170727260  221801763      -81.0
#1       B  1604716749  829186592      -48.0
#2       C   661473481  553698141      -16.0

df.dtypes
#c2_name      object
#Q1_GMV        int64
#Q2_GMV        int64
#growth(%)   float64

#Add a decimal type to the `df` to reproduce your error.
df.loc[2, 'growth(%)'] = Decimal(2.1511231)

# Now styling will throw an error:
(df.style
  .background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=['growth(%)'])
  .set_caption('This is a custom caption.'))
```

> TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and
>   'float'", 'occurred at index growth(%)')

```
# Make the Decimals into floats
df['growth(%)'] = df['growth(%)'].astype('float')
(df.style
  .background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=['growth(%)'])
  .set_caption('This is a custom caption.'))
```

[image]

If you need to keep the `Decimal` type, consider writing a function that just converts the type for styling and display.

Comment: thanks, it worked. can i get a descending version of the gradient color such that the highest negative value is dark green and so on?

Comment: @NamanDoshi use `reverse=True` that is, `cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True, reverse=True)` when you define the colormap